# Configure Navbar with 2nd level

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

Probably an easy question, but I am pretty new to this and do not get it to work so far. Can someone tell me how I can make it work that "Location A" and "Location B" are only appearing on the navbar, when "Locations" will be clicked? So "Location A" and "Location B" should be on the second level and the page should not reload.

```
@implements IDisposable

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WeatherStation</a>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" />

<div class="nav-scrollable" onclick="document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler').click()">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="bi bi-house-door-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown" href="Locations">
                <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Locations
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Locations/Location A">
                <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Location A
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Locations/Location B">
                <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Location B
            </NavLink>
        </div>

@code {
    private string? currentUrl;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
    }

    private void OnLocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(e.Location);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this code

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer //Add rendermode for interactive if you are using .net8
...
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown" @onclick="@(()=>{display=!display;})">
                <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Locations
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        @if (display)
        {
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Locations/Location A">
                    <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Location A
                </NavLink>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Locations/Location B">
                    <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Location B
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        }
    </nav>
</div>
@code{
    private bool display = false;
}
```